# stripe.confirmOxxoPayment ERROR node js server

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, stripe

Actualmente estoy ocupando oxxo mediante stripe en mi servidor node js, pero no sé cómo implementarlo, ya que en el ejemplo de github de la documentación da una vista html y yo solo estoy generando las funciones enviando el email, el amount, names por medio de la api, puedo generar el paymentIntent de stripe pero cuando intento usar stripe.confirmOxxoPayment me genera un error.
Anexo código de cómo lo estoy implementando

```js
const Stripe = require('stripe');

exports.create_payment_intent = async (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;
  const stripe = Stripe('KEY');

  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: data.price,
    currency: 'mxn',
    payment_method_types: ['oxxo']
  });

  console.log('paymentIntent', paymentIntent)

  payWithOxxo(clientSecret, data)

};
 


var payWithOxxo = function(clientSecret, data) {
  console.log('client', clientSecret)
  const stripe = Stripe('KEY');
  stripe
    .confirmOxxoPayment(
      clientSecret,
      {
        payment_method: {
          billing_details: {
            name: data.name,
            email: data.email
          }
        }
      }
    )
    .then(function(result) {
      console.log('data intent', result)

      if (result.error) {
        
        // Show error to your customer
        showError(result.error.message);
      }
    });

}
```

Y este es el error que me arroja al intentar hacer esta implementación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué versión de Stripe.js estás utilizando? Te recomiendo actualizar a la más reciente (v 1.11.0)

Comment: "stripe": "^7.1.0" esta es la que se me indica

Comment: Te recomiendo que utilices "^8.132.0"

Comment: Te funcionó actualizando la librería?

Comment: No, sigue sin funcionarme

Comment: Podrías publicar el proyecto con sus dependencias etc en un sitio como codesandbox.io o GitHub? Eso me ayudaría a analizar el problema.

Comment: Es https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-joliot-09duy?file=/server.js

Comment: No me corre ese sandbox, pero aquí hay un ejemplo completo que puedes modificar: https://codesandbox.io/s/stripe-sample-oxxo-payment-q66ty

Comment: Sí, es el que viene de ejemplo en la API, pero lo que necesito es ya mandarle los parámetros de nombre y correo para que solo me arroje el pago, pero es a lo que no puedo llegar. Leí que puedes obtener este pago mediante una url pero no puedo acceder a ella, solo puedo crear el payment intent pero ya no puedo crear el pago con oxxo para que me arroje el voucher